# OTP generation without using third part API

Tags: javascript, sms, one-time-password

How can I send a OTP to  my application user without using third party SMS gateways.

If 'yes' then how can I use ? Can anyone please help in this .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u can tried anything for this ?

Comment: I have gone through many sites but i couldn't find anything@MohammadAli

Comment: I want to send an OTP to the user without using third party (API/SMS gateways) for confirm the proper user.do we have any  code or tool or api that are  free  so that i can integrate into my code to send an OTP  to the user for  authentication. @sma